# (co | in)variance of Higher Kinded type parameter

Tags: scala, types, covariance

the code in question

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def map[A, B](f: A => B): F[A] => F[B]
}

sealed abstract class Free[F[_], A]
case class Return[F[_], A](x: A) extends Free[F, A]
case class Suspend[F[_], A](x: F[Free[F, A]]) extends Free[F, A]
case class Bind[F[_], A, B](x: () => Free[F, A], f: A => Free[F, B]) extends Free[F, B]

// this is the problem child
def liftF[F[_], A](x: => F[A])(implicit F: Functor[F]) = 
  Suspend[F, A](F.map { Return[F, A] }(x))
```

Now for some reason in the eclipse scala ide I'm getting a error with liftF
  this error

```
- type mismatch; found : F[core01.Free.Return[F,A]] required: F[core01.Free[F,A]] Note: core01.Free.Return[F,A] <: core01.Free[F,A], but type 
 F is invariant in type _. You may wish to define _ as +_ instead. (SLS 4.5)
```

Now in the scalaz source there's no variance annotation, so what's the deal here? why the need for the variance annotation? is there are really need or is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have the functor arguments backwards on `F.map`. Give this a try:

```
  def liftF[F[_], A](x: => F[A])(implicit F: Functor[F]) =
    Suspend[F, A](F.map(x) { Return[F, A] } )

  println(liftF(List(1, 2)))
  "Suspend(List(Return(1), Return(2)))"
```

Note that either way you apply the elements to functor map you'll get the same result (you're version and the scalaz version):

```
def mapReverse[F[_], A, B](implicit F: Functor[F]) = {
  (f:A => B) => (fa:F[A]) => F.map(fa)(f)
}

val reverse = mapReverse(F)({
  Return[F, A]
})(x)

val normal = F.map(x)({
  Return[F, A]
})
```

In this case `reverse` and `normal` are both `F[Return[F, A]]`. The way you apply the parameters is only helpful in the context of `Suspend`:

```
Suspend[F, A](F.map(x)({ Return[F, A] })) // works great

Suspend[F, A](normal) // fails to compile
Suspend[F, A](reverse) // fails to compile
```

I'm sure if you dig through the scala language spec long enough you can find out why the type inference works this way. If I had to guess, when `fa` is applied to `F.map` you get a function that's of type `(A => B) => F[B]`. So the compiler probably looks and sees that Suspend takes a `Free` so it makes this `(A => Free[F, A]) => F[Free[F, A]]` which will gladly take `Return[F, A].apply` as an argument. When you apply the arguments the other way you're strongly typed to `Return` instead of inferring a function `Free`.

Comment: that's not the problem, I just included the definition of map in the background code for clarification.

Comment: I see. Try swapping them around in your implementation like the scalaz impl `def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]`. I think you're just in scala inference hell right now.